# Rendering obstacles with Android using Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, rendering, sprite

I am trying my best to render a texture to the screen. I've also tried to render a sprite but none has succeeded. From my understanding the camera needs a viewport and its best to use world units when rendering your world. I get the idea about units and it makes sense. But if you say your world is 100X100 then your sprite background must also be 100X100. I still don't get it how is supposed to cover the entire device screen(android phone). I guess providing assets at different resolutions or implementing a stretchviewport might be ideal. Also, I am trying to implement the private moveCamera method. My goal is 
to have the camera move in random ways displaying parts of my texture. When i ran the code for the first time, I saw that the camera moved but then the screen
turned red and then black. I think I might have to clamp the camera to force it to stay within the bounds of the asset. Please help me set this functionality up.

Well here is my code:(Cant render a thing)

```
public class myGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter{

 @Override
 public void Create(){
 scenery= new Texture...;
 sprity= new Sprite(new Texture(..));
 sprity.setPosition(0f,0f);
 sprity.setSize(100f,100f);

 w= Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
 h= Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

 moveX=0f;//float value
 moveY=0f;//float value
 time= System.currentTimeMillis();

 camera= new OrthoGraphicCamera(30,30*(h/w));
 camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2f,camera.viewportHeight/2f,0);
 camera.update();

 }

 @Override
 public void resize(int width, int height) {
 camera.viewportWidth = 30f;        
 camera.viewportHeight = 30f * (height/width);
 camera.update();

}

@Override
public void render () {

moveCamera();
camera.update();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batch.begin();
batch.draw(scenery, 0, 0);
batch.end();

}

public void moveCamera(){

if(System.currentTimeMillis()-time>2000){

double random=Math.round(Math.random()*100);
double random2=Math.round(Math.random()*100);
double d=random/10;
double e=random2/10;
int f=(int)d;
int g=(int)e;
moveX=moveX+f;
moveY=moveY+g;

time=System.currentTimeMillis();
camera.translate(moveX,moveY,0);
camera.update();

}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is on this line:

```
camera.viewportHeight = 30f * (height/width);
```

`height` and `width` are both ints, so if `width` is more than `height`, `(height/width) == 0`, so you are setting your view height to 0.

Cast one of them to a float, and your problem will be fixed.

```
camera.viewportHeight = 30f * ((float)height/width);
```

Note that you are setting the world width to 30, not 100 like you were describing.

I don't think StretchViewport is a good solution, because stuff will look distorted. I recommend using ExtendViewport and give it dimensions based on one of the extremes (4:3 or 16:9). Then make your background big enough to cover the extra area to reach into the other extreme.

For example, you could make a `new ExtendViewport(400, 300)` so it is designed for a 4:3 ratio. Then make your background image at least 534 x 300 so it will still cover the whole area if you get a 16:9 screen (the opposite extreme).

Or the other way around: Make a `new ExtendViewport(800, 450)` so it is designed for a 16:9 ratio. Then make your background image at least 800 x 600 so it will still cover the whole area if you get a 4:3 screen (the opposite extreme).

Comment: what if I position my camera such that the x coordinate is the negative of half of the viewport width and the y coordinate is zero, does it mean I will only see half of my viewport and the remaining screen will be a black screen? What is the default camera position in Libgdx? I've heard is at the top left corner, whereas the default position for a sprite is at the bottom left corner of the phone screen? @Tenfour04

Comment: The position of the camera will not cause cropping like you described. You'll see the part of the world that is in areas with negative coordinates, if you put anything there. The default position of an orthographic camera in Libgdx (and OpenGL ) is with (0, 0) at the center of the screen and the Y-axis pointing up. If you use a viewport and choose to center the camera with the `update` method, then (0,0) will be in the bottom left. The top left corner is only if you choose to flip the Y axis on your camera, which you might want to do if you are already used to that from using Flash or similar.